# how can I capitalize words in c# .net

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.5

I'm trying to capitalize words with c# applying this

```
Regex.Replace(source,"\b.",m=>m.Value.ToUpper())
```

It doesn't work.

I want to do this with c#:

```
"this is an example string".replace(/\b./g,function(a){ return a.toLocaleUpperCase()});
```

Output string: `"This Is An Example String"`

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I don't agree that this question is exactly a duplicate. The linked to question has much more specific needs about which words should and should not be capitalized. If anything this question is more general and the other is too specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you need to escape your search term, as it involves the '\' character. Use either `@"\b."` or `"\\b."` for your search term.

Comment: Oh man thanks, You'have been the solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean just the first letter of each word try this:
ToTitleCase

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx

```
string s = "this is an example string";
TextInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;

string uppercase = ti.ToTitleCase(s);
```

Comment: ToTitleCase() doesn't exist anymore in .NET Windows Store. You will need to rely on ToUpper() only.

Comment: It's not in Metro, but it is in .NET 4.5, the question does not mention Metro and is tagged with .net-4.5

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply try this

```
string upperString = mystring.ToUpper();
```

If you want to first letter of each word in upper case then you can try this.

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
string capitalString=textInfo.ToTitleCase(myString));
```

Comment: This returns THIS IS AN EXAMPLE STRING

Comment: 'cause i want to capitalize names

Comment: Do you expect the name "mcfly" to be capitalized as "McFly"? All of the approaches I've seen will only make it "Mcfly". To put it shortly: capitalizing is hard or impossible if you try to take all cases into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can also capitalize each word by aggregating.

```
"this is an example string"
.Split(' ')
.Aggregate("", (acc, word) => acc + " " + char.ToUpper(word[0]) + word.Substring(1))
```

Comment: public static string Capitalize(this string source) {  Regex.Replace(source.ToLower(),@"\b.",m=>m.Value.ToUpper()); }

Comment: That works well for your example.  However, watch out for words with capitals not at the beginning.  For example, "Mcdonalds".Capitalize() returns "Mcdonalds"

Comment: *`"McDonalds".Capitalize()` returns "Mcdonalds"

Comment: sorry, i'm cuban and  here not exist that kind of names.

Comment: i would have to make a parameter to except words